# Firefox warning messages on the trilogy sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, firefox

I realised that Firefox gives the following warning messages every time I surf the trilogy sites.

Firefox error console screeny for SuperUser:

[image]

Firefox error console screeny for StackOverflow, ServerFault and Meta (exactly the same for these sites):

[image]

I observed the same error console outputs from 2 different PCs on different ISPs. Maybe those warnings are not so important but I just wanted to inform the developers...

Comment: There's some humor in an error message that says "Expected 'important' but found 'ie7'."

Comment: There is actually `width:650px!ie7;padding-bottom:20px!ie7;` in the css file. wondering thats a trick to IE7 but ignore to other browsers?

Comment: also found  `pre{max-height:none\9;}` , I think `\9` doing nothing though.

Comment: @S.Mark: we can't know until we test with and without it on IE5-9, Opera 9.x-10.x, Chrome 2-5, Safari 2-4, Firefox 2.x-3.7, Konqueror, Epiphany and `links`. Who knows what that is fixing. Or may be it's just a typo.

Comment: This reminds me [of something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/237825#237825 "If you are happy and you know it, Syntax Error").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using [CSS tricks](http://webdeveloperplus.com/css/25-incredibly-useful-css-tricks-you-should-know/) to target different browsers.

*Bad Jeff, [bad](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/03/05/5-reasons-to-avoid-css-hacks-and-conditional-stylesheets/)!*
* Rubs Jeff nose in the CSS *
*Use [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) instead!*

They are generally harmless, but are more work than they are worth.

Comment: Conditional Comment stylesheets are irritating to change, though :(

Comment: @Phoshi: but is better than CSS tricks misbehaving on different browsers.

Comment: @json: I wouldn't say throwing up an error the vast majority of users will never see is particularly misbehaving, but otherwise I agree. IE is irritating in general :(

Comment: @Phoshi: CSS tricks make future proofing harder. If I visit the site with *New Browser 3.11™*, it might misbehave in a really bad way, while conditional comments allow for a cleaner action. Of course, if you are targeting Opera or Webkit and not Firefox (or any other combination), you might be more restricted in your choices.

Comment: conditional comments require changes to the HTML which is lame. I am open to *conditional CSS* but such a thing does not exist. Sadly.

Comment: @Jeff: you could also sniff the browser to have conditional CSS, but that would be probably even more evil. You might be able to reduce footprint with that though.